# Silverlight 4 OOB application and Images folder

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I am developing a Silverlight 4 application which displays items in a carousel control. The items are parsed form an XML file and then loaded as an image which can be double clicked to open a website, file, image etc.

I am already running in higher privileges mode (out of browser) to access the Xml file which sits in a subfolder of the application.

I can load the images fine when they are added to the project as they are included as resources. However, I need to be able to load images which aren't individually added to the project. Instead, I would like to add all images in a particular folder as resources.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

From [Advanced Silverlight Out of Browser- Introduction](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/tutorials/silverlight-4/advanced-silverlight-out-of-browser-introduction/#Exercise3)

> When running in a trusted environment,
>   you can access only files in user
>   folders, specifically the MyDocuments,
>   MyMusic, MyPictures, and MyVideos
>   folders

So, if you want to access folders other than this, you would probably need to run some sort of service, which has the proper rights. What kind of service depends on where this app is running. Could be a WCF service, or a simple WebService, if you can run a webserver on the machine. Otherwise, you'd need a windows service of some sort.